# Not able to set category for AVAudioSession

Tags: ios, swift, avaudiosession, avaudiorecorder

Trying to record audio with `AVAudioSession`. But not able to set category end up with ambiguous without context error.

I'm using swift 4.

```
@objc func setupRecorder() {
    recordingSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

    do {
        try recordingSession?.setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .default)
        try recordingSession.setActive(true)
        recordingSession.requestRecordPermission() { [unowned self] allowed in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if allowed {
                    self.startRecording()
                } else {
                    // failed to record!
                }
            }
        }
    } catch {
        // failed to record!
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What version of `Swift` are you using? It's better to include code as **Text** instead of screenshots.

Comment: I'm using swift 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using "Swift4", then the method to set category is different, i.e.,

```
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(String, mode: String, options: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions)
```

ad you can use this via following way:

```
try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, mode: AVAudioSessionModeDefault, options: AVAudioSessionPortBuiltInSpeaker)
```